How to extract the metadata of a files in a SharePoint list using R?
I would like to extract the metadata of the files in a SharePoint list using R.

Here is an approach that can be considered :
library(httr)
library(jsonlite
        
call <- "https://sharepoint.xxx/xxx/xxx/_api/web/lists('xxx')/Files"
rest_call <- GET(call, httr::authenticate("", "", type = "ntlm")) 
text <- rawToChar(rest_call$content)
list_Metadata <- fromJSON(text)
list_Metadata


Here is another approach that can be considered :
library(RDCOMClient)
oXMLHTTP <- COMCreate("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
oXMLHTTP$Open("GET", "https://sharepoint.xxx/xxx/xxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxx')/files", TRUE)
oXMLHTTP$SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
oXMLHTTP$SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
oXMLHTTP$Send()
oXMLHTTP$Status()
info_Json <- oXMLHTTP$responseText()
fromJSON(info_Json)


You can also extract the SharePoint metadata of an Excel file using the following approach :
library(RDCOMClient)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("//sharepoint.xxx/xxx/xxx/test.xlsx")
xlWbk$ContentTypeProperties("Direction")$Value() 

